# Как через библиотеку schedule по праздникам(То есть каждый год) вызывать определённые функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x, schedule

Я спрашивал у чатжпт помощь, он мне показал такой код/

```
schedule.every().year.at("01-01 00:00").do(my_job)
```

Однако я получил ошибку, которая гласит, что аттрибута year не существует.
Я попытался найти официальную документацию, но их много и все разные и непонятно, какая официальная, однако я так и не нашёл в них способа вызывать так, как мне нужно.

Я могу как-то с помощью этой библиотеки вызывать каждый год в определённую дату и время функции?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я вижу в репозитории библиотеки на гитхабе, функциональность, позволяющая делать запуски раз в год, сейчас находится в разработке:

https://github.com/dbader/schedule/issues/487

https://github.com/dbader/schedule/pull/565/commits

В качестве временного решения могу предложить вам использовать ежедневный запуск задачи, а уже внутри `my_job` проверять, что сегодня нужная дата.

PS: А советы чатжпт советую воспринимать с долей скепсиса - он имеет обыкновение додумывать по аналогии про те вещи, которых не знает.